# Canvas size in dispatchDraw of custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm facing a problem in my custom layout, which is an extension of LinearLayout. All I want to achieve is to draw some shapes on the canvas of the layout.

Therefore I did something like this:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();

        Log.d(TAG, "canvas width: " + width);
        Log.d(TAG, "canvas height: " + height);

        // do some drawing on the canvas ...
    }
}
```

I left out the part where I do the actual drawing because it doesn't have to do anything with my problem, I guess.

My problem is that on pre-ICS (or maybe pre-Honeycomb) the canvas seems to be the size of the whole screen instead of just the part where the layout should be drawn. Therefore my drawings end up at the wrong place.

For example, on a HTC Desire the log output from above is:

```
canvas.width: 480
canvas.height: 800
```

Whereas the height should be smaller because there are other elements above and below the layout.

The problem does not exist on ICS, where I get a canvas which is exactly the size of my layout.

Comment: Actually it seems to be a bit more complicated. In the initial dispatchDraw() call i get the correct canvas size:

    canvas width: 480
  canvas height: 690

But there immediately follows a second dispatchDraw() call which has the canvas set to 480x800.

Comment: OK, the 690 seem to be the full display size without the status bar. So it's still not the correct height of the layout.

Comment: OK, I just found out that I should use getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() which seems to be working on all platform versions.

Comment: ah that was going to be my answer, but measureWidth and measuredHeight is not the correct api to use in this case. You should use getWidth and getHeight. measuredWidth and hight is same as width and height most of the time but it can not be guaranteed to be same all the time. getWidth/Height will give you the actual width & height of the view. Also from the documentation, dispatchDraw is called by the draw. I have been overloading Draw for my usage.

Comment: You're right, I should've used getWidth/getHeight. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use dispatch draw? Why not use invalidate and let the framework figure out the canvas size.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. As far as I understand dispatchDraw is used in ViewGroups to do work just before the child views get drawn. And as the documentation says (canvas => the canvas on which to draw the view)
I expect to get the canvas where the layout is drawn on.